# JQuery UI Menu - first li has extra height

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, menu, menuitem

I've been trying to implement jq-ui's menu, but my first item of the menu is always appearing with extra height (please see screenshot) How do I get this to work properly? (All menu items should be of same size) I'm using JQuery 1.11.0. The JSFiddle is up on http://jsfiddle.net/rsreeram84/YhLh5/23/  but it's not working (would like to know why, but that's a secondary concern)

```
    <table style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:60px;width:100%;z-index:1;background-color:white;height:1px;border-style: solid none solid none;border-color:black; border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
        <td align=center id="menubtn-abt" width="175px" class="menubtn">About</td>
        <td align=center id="menubtn-settings" width="175px" class="menubtn">Hello2</td>
        <td align=center id="logo-placeholder-menubar" style="padding:0px;border-style:solid;background-color:white"></td>
        <td align=center id="menubtn-tools" width="175px" class="menubtn" onclick="showMenu()">Tools</td>
        <td align=center id="menubtn-results" class="menubtn" width="175px">Results</td>
    </tr>
</table>
  <ul id="menu" style="width:100px;">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3
      <ul>
        <li>Item 3-1</li>
        <li>Item 3-2
          <ul>
            <li>Item 3-2-1</li>
            <li>Item 3-2-2</li>
            <li>Item 3-2-3</li>
            <li>Item 3-2-4</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 3-3</li>
        <li>Item 3-4</li>
        <li>Item 3-5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</body>
<script>
$("#menu").menu();  
    $("#menu").position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        of: "#menubtn-results"

    });
    function showMenu()
    {
        $("#menu").show();
    }
    $("#menu").hide();

</script>
```

[image: Item 1 is taller than it should be]

Please help!

Comment: We'd need to see the CSS as well that applies to the submenu to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YhLh5/25/

Menu shows on click in Tools button.

```
        <td align=center id="menubtn-tools" width="175px" class="menubtn" onclick="$('#menu').show();">Tools</td>
```

This is working and I cannot reproduce your problem under Chrome. Can you check if it's working for you?

Comment: So menu() wasn't loading because I didn't have the script tag?

Since it works on fiddle, I tried a different tack and discovered that the extra space was coming in because of an image I was using. Wouldn't have thought of it if you hadn't gotten it to work in the first place, so thanks, Kamil!